# Finding the probability that each apple in a randomly selected bag has a mass less than 105 grams.

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, binomial-distribution, standard-deviation

> I am practising normal distribution exam type questions but I am stuck
>   at this one:

The masses of individual apples sold in a food store are normally distributed. The supplier who provides the store with apples knows that 75% of the apples have a mass greater than 85 grams and that 10% of the apples have a mass greater than 120 grams.

(a) Find the value of the mean and the value of the standard deviation

> So I successfully found the mean (`μ=97.1`) and the standard deviation
>   (`δ=17.9`) by calculating the z-scores of the given probabilities.

The apples are always sold in bags containing 6 apples.

> So how do I find the following probabilities for the grouped items? Do I have to use binomial distribution (6 trials) or something else?

(b) Find the probability that each apple in a randomly selected bag has a mass less than 105
 grams.

(c) How many apples (to the nearest whole number) from a randomly selected bag would you
 expect to have a mass greater than 90 grams?

> Thank you for the guidance in advance!

Comment: Yes (b) and (c) involve a binomial distribution

Comment: @Henry but how do I get the number of trials?

Comment: For the binomial distribution, the number of trials is $n=6$ as you suggest. You have to calculate the $p$ parameters from "less than $105$ grams" or "greater than $90$ grams"

Comment: @Henry ok, so the no. of trials is n=6 and I calculated the p to be p=0.67, but still I would need an x variable, that is the no. of successful outcomes.

Comment: So for each of the six apples to have a mass below $105$, you need $X=6$ in the binomial, which gives a probability of about ${6 \choose 6}0.67^6 0.33^0= 0.67^6 \approx 0.09$ or $9\%$

Comment: @Henry oh I see, great, thank you, I was confused

Answer (score 1):

So the b part can be solved using a binomial distribution:

${6 \choose 6}0.67^6 0.33^0= 0.67^6 \approx 0.09$